# Time complexity of stl set_symmetric_difference

Tags: c++, stl, time-complexity

I was reading the time complexity of stl [set_symmetric_difference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_symmetric_difference/)

It says:

> Up to linear in 2*(count1+count2)-1 (where countX is the distance
>   between firstX and lastX): Compares and assigns elements.

I'm confuse with the statement "*countX is the distance between firstX and lastX*".

Please clarify it with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm confused with the statement "countX is the distance between firstX and lastX".

From the example on the same page you are linking to:

> `first1, last1`
>
> Input iterators to the initial and final positions of the first sorted sequence. > The range used is [first1,last1), which contains all the elements between first1 > and last1, including the element pointed by first1 but not the element pointed
>   by last1.
>
> `first2, last2`
>
> Input iterators to the initial and final positions of the second sorted sequence. The range used is [first2,last2).

So, `count` is the [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) (i.e. number of hops) between the sorted elements of iterators representing first and last element in the data structure (array in the example). For first (sorted: `5 10 15 20 25`) that would be 5.

As for the [complexity of `std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance#Complexity):

> Linear.
>
> However, if InputIt additionally meets the requirements of RandomAccessIterator, complexity is constant.

Comment: Is it simply means O(number of elements in Set1 + number of elements in Set2)?

Comment: You said " For first (sorted: 5 10 15 20 25) that would be 25 - 5 = 20". Does it means the complexity depends on elements in it rather than number of elements? Because if I had set s1 = {1, 20000000000}, set s2 = {2}, does it mean the complexity would be O(10^10)?

Comment: It was a mistake, the distance is 5 in this case. And yes *in this case* it is the number of elements but it is basically `std::distance`, which is the number of hops, which is linear or constant.

Comment: Can you please highlight a scenario where the time complexity is not linear? because it says O(count 1+ count2) which seams linear to me.

Comment: Every data structure that will satisfy `RandomAccessIterator` will have a constant time `std::distance`.

Comment: Thanks got the idea. @syntagma, could you please look at this relevant question I have asked in another post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46129667/how-to-simulate-xor-of-sets-using-bitwise-operators

Comment: @user3243499 -- "number of elements in Set1" -- yes, sort of, but there don't have to be any **sets** involved. There are two **sorted sequences**, which can come from anywhere. I've always found the names `set_xxx` a bit confusing. The `set` part is an analogy, not a requirement.